I am trying to push npm artifact to azure devops artifact feed. Getting error 500- internal server error
I am trying to push npm artifact to azure devops artifact feed. Getting error (not able to get the error code as well- initially i was getting 500- internal server error)
I have given all the required permission shown in the above diagram-
Azure devops server - On-prem, 2020 version
enter image description here
Tried below commands for testing a sample npm pacakge from same network level.
npm init
npm pack
npm install
npm publish

.npmrc configuration is below config
registry=https://azuredevops.abc.internal/kakanksha1/_packaging/kakanksha1/npm/registry/ 
                        
always-auth=true
strict-ssl=false

; begin auth token
//azuredevops.abc.internal/kakanksha1/_packaging/kakanksha1/npm/registry/:username=kakanksha1
//azuredevops.abc.internal/kkakanksha1/_packaging/kakanksha1/npm/registry/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//azuredevops.abc.internal/kkakanksha1/_packaging/kakanksha1/npm/registry/:email=abc@gmail.com
//azuredevops.abc.internal/kkakanksha1/_packaging/kakanksha1/npm/:username=kakanksha1
//azuredevops.abc.internal/kkakanksha1/_packaging/kakanksha1/npm/:_password=[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]
//azuredevops.abc.internal/kakanksha1/_packaging/kakanksha1/npm/:email=abc@gmail.com

; end auth token

https-proxy=https://proxy.abc.internal:8080

proxy=https://proxy.abc.internal:8080


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi @AkankshaSrivastava, Good day to you, Have you got a chance to check my sample .npmrc file below? May I know if npm publish works after correcting the collection name in the URLs of your .npmrc configuration? Thx for the update.

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT, The error you mentioned in .npmrc is a typo error while posting the question someone modified, also .npmrc file is correct. I have replaced the actual collection scope feed with the sample name - kakanksha1. No this isn't fixing my error at all. The issue is not with npmrc, it's with proxy, somewhere at the network level it's getting blocked as the setup is very restrictive. Still debugging it.

Is the server URL resolvable after your machine access the required network via proxy? Upon checking the edit history, the collection names from the URLs of your .npmrc were not the same in both your original and current post. It is still suggested double checking the correct collection in those URLs.

Please verify your Azure DevOps collection name first. From the screenshot, we could see you might have the permissions to push to an Azure Artifacts feed in the collection of ramiMSFTDevOps, while from the .npmrc configuration file, you seemed to have been trying to publish packages into the collection of kakanksha1 or kkakanksha1. The collection names from the registry URls were not the same.
Here is my .npmrc file for your reference.
registry=http://aztfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/CollectionScopeFeed/npm/registry/ 
                        
always-auth=true

//aztfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/CollectionScopeFeed/npm/registry/:username=DefaultCollection
//aztfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/CollectionScopeFeed/npm/registry/:_password="[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]"
//aztfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/CollectionScopeFeed/npm/registry/:email=abc@gmail.com
//aztfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/CollectionScopeFeed/npm/:username=DefaultCollection
//aztfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/CollectionScopeFeed/npm/:_password="[BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]"
//aztfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/CollectionScopeFeed/npm/:email=abc@gmail.com

To get the value of [BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN] to be replaced in the .npmrc file:

From a command/shell prompt run;
node -e "require('readline') .createInterface({input:process.stdin,output:process.stdout,historySize:0}) .question('PAT> ',p => { b64=Buffer.from(p.trim()).toString('base64');console.log(b64);process.exit(); })"


Paste your personal access token value when the command in step 1 asked for an input interactively and press Enter/Return;

Copy the Base64 encoded value and replace both [BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN] values in your .npmrc file like above with the encoded value.


